# temporary email address concept

Tags: java, email

I would like to do a similar concept on how the site craigslist is able to create a temporary email address for a seller in order to hide the seller real email address (to keep it private) when someone wants to contact the seller.  If you send and email to the temporary email address, it will actually go to the seller’s real email box.
I would like to know how this is done?  Do I need to install an email server? What do I need to actually implement this ?

Any suggestions or reading material would be great.

Comment: at the very least you need the ability to create/delete email accounts and forward them to a real account, for that, you'll need an emil server and manipulate it directly...

Answer (score 5):

You have a lot of things to learn if you're asking this broad a question.

1. Install an SMTP server such as Postfix
2. Configure aliases that forward mail to the "real" destination
3. Have your application update the alias configuration whenever you need to create or delete an address.

How to actually accomplish all of this is way beyond what SO is for.

Comment: ...and that's just the bare minimum to setup the functionality. How do oyu make viable business model? How do you deal with high volume messaging? How do you ensure adequate security?.....

Comment: All excellent questions, which MUST be asked, but totally off-topic for SO :-)  Maybe onstartups.com, or the StackExchange proposed site for startups?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a "catchall" mailbox so that all e-mail would go to it.  Then you need to write a routine to check the emails and parse the "to" address, matching it to the real address in your database.